# Pipeline dataflow using C++11 async features

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, pipeline, dataflow

I'm trying to implement a multithreaded pipeline dataflow framework with the following features:

1. The pipeline can be described as an acyclic directed graph. Each node performs some processing and has arbitrary number of inputs of arbitrary types and one output of arbitrary type.
2. For each given input data instance each node should be executed not more that once, after that the result should be cached. Although this cache shouldn't persist in memory longer that required and should be deleted when no longer needed by any other nodes.
3. Each node should support lazy evaluation, i.e. should be executed only at the moment it's output is needed by some another node.

Is it possible to implement this by using C++11 multithreading features, especially `std::future`, `std::promise` and `std::async`? Can anybody give a clue?

Comment: Is it possible to reuse the pipeline ? That is, do you want a structure that describes the pipeline, and then instantiate it once per input token to run it ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it actually is fairly trivial using an `async` framework.

If you look at [std::launch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) you will realize there is a deferred mode:

- `std::launch::deferred`: the task is executed on the calling thread the first time its result is requested (lazy evaluation)

Thus, you can launch a task and have it executed only when the result is needed. However, since you mention an acyclic graph, you probably want to share the result: a `std::future` (as returned by a call to `std::async`) cannot be shared; you need a `std::shared_future` for this.

And thus, putting it altogether:

```
// Disclaimer:
// Compiles but does not run, but I have not figured it out.
// See: http://ideone.com/XZ49Dg

#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::shared_future<std::string> greeting = std::async(std::launch::deferred, []() {
        std::string s;
        std::cout << "Enter how you would like to be greeted: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        return s;
    });

    std::shared_future<int> choice = std::async(std::launch::deferred, []() {
        int c = 0;
        std::cout << "Pick any integer: ";
        std::cin >> c;
        return c;
    });

    std::shared_future<void> complete = std::async(std::launch::deferred, [=]() mutable {
        std::string const g = greeting.get();
        int const c = choice.get();

        std::cout << "Hello " << g << ", you picked " << c << "!\n";
    });

    complete.wait();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though it's not clear how different input tokens should be handled and how to clear the stored value in future when it's no longer required (i.e. in a sequential pipeline where the memory should be cleared after passing execution to a subsequent stage). `shared_future` should be somehow instantiated and passed around inside the graph itself, not as a global variable. Not sure how to do this though.

Comment: how did you implement pipeline in c++? @lizarisk